# 80040154 Class not registered error even though clsid is in registry

Tags: .net, windows, com, registry

I'm trying to use HtmlSnap to generate images from html. I have it installed and running fine locally, but when I deploy it to our dev server, I get the following error:

`A critical error has occurred. Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {*Redacted*} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

I've checked in the registry, the class is there. I've used regsvr32, it succeeds, still error. I've set permissions on the registry key, and on the component service to allow the app pool id access. I have no idea why this isnt working.

Thoughts?

Comment: A 64-bit operating system is the usual problem.  Use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe to register 32-bit COM components.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon.exe if that doesn't help.

Comment: syswow regsvr didnt help, so i procmonned. So, the program was looking for the clsid in HKCR, and the class wasnt registered there. I added the key (copied from my local machine) and now i get `8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).`

Comment: I'd say there is a permission error on registration. There is no reason it should only half register. Does the user you are registering under have full admin rights?

Comment: I had a problem similar to this usually it is registration. what is your operating system and is the dll 32-bit or 64-bit?  I have a current project I used in c++ that gave me class not registered when I did not have a com component registered properly.  Have you used ole view to see if the class is registered properly? Usually it will show up under object classes->all objects if it is com and registered properly.

Comment: If you want to use a 32bit COM library from a .net app, make sure the .net app is compiled to x86, otherwise .net will be looking for 64bit COM registry info if you are running in a 64bit environment.

Comment: I came across this question hoping for some help, and all I discovered is that COM is quite finicky. In my scenario I ended up copying the .dll and it's dependencies into the System32 folder on the server and running regsvr32 from there and then if finally worked for me.